# EB not able to access file in .ebextensions

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have the following `container_command` in my `django.config` that points to a script at path `.ebextensions/supervise.sh`:

```
container_commands:
  01-supervise:
    command: .ebextensions/supervise.sh
```

However when I deploy I get a permission error. `Command failed on instance. Return code: 126 Output: /bin/sh: .ebextensions/supervise.sh:
Permission denied.`

I'm wondering what is required to set permissions correctly? What is causing this error? As far as I can tell the issue isn't well documented. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, it looks like scripts lose their executable bit when packing/unpacking them.

Try resetting the executable bit before running them:

```
container_commands:
  01-set-exec-bit:
    command: chmod +x .ebextensions/deployschema.sh
    test: "[ -f .ebextensions/deployschema.sh ]"
  02-create-table:
    command: ".ebextensions/deployschema.sh"
    leader_only: true
```

From: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=262121

Answer (score 0):

First of all do not put you .sh files in .ebextensions folder. Create a separate folder in your app root and put it there. And update the .config file with following:

```
container_commands:
  01-supervise:
    command: "sh scripts/supervise.sh"
```

I know i am late in answering this but hopefully this will help someone struggling with this.